# anaconda 3 base environment sets wrong PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pythonpath, anaconda3

This afternoon I did a clean install of the OS in my Mac Mini, then downloaded the last release of Anaconda and installed it.
I did this many time, but never have I faced issues right from the start.

I tried simply importing some packages, like `Pandas` of `Numpy`, but got errors.
After some attempts to update `pip`, I realised that Python was looking in the wrong place!!
This is confirmed by printing `sys.path`.

So I open my `.bash_profile` and commented out the `EXPORT PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/Library...` line.
Unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Does anyone know how to fix the PYTHONPATH issue?
Should I just remove the lines which activate the base environment and create a clean new one?
Isn't there a way to simply fix the base environment?

Thanks for the support. Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by commenting out also the line

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
```

in the `.bash_profile` file.

I'm don't really like it, because it doesn't feel as a clean solution, but it works.

Hopefully this might help someone else who encounters the same issue.